# In photoshop 7, how can I change the color of text that has already been saved as an image

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, colors, photoshop-7

I have a photoshop file which is a bunch of text but it was saved as an image (so I can't use any of the text tools to change it).

Its basically black text and I want to change it to purple.

I tried using the color replace tool but you can only move sliders around the existing color so since its black it just turns to grey if I slide it.

How can I change black image to purple in adobe photoshop 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Hue/Saturation Layer Mask and turn the Lightness up and Colorize "ON". That will allow you to change the colour of a black object.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the layer you're trying to edit
2. Select blending options
3. From blending options styles section(left side of the menu), select or check Color Overlay.
4. You can pick color from Color Overlay menu (right side).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option for that, because Photoshop-7 won't know its text.  What you can try however is taking the "Magic Wand Tool" and selecting the letters (I hope its just a line or two...).

After selecting the letters, try to change it's color.

If you need help with this, just ask.

ALSO: you may be able to use OCR software to recognize the text, then copy it into MS Word, then change its color then put it back into Photoshop, but if the background is anything other than a simple white, you'd probably have a problem putting it back in.

**Uploading the picture would help**

Comment: when you say: "after selecting the letters, try to change it's color", which tool would you use to change its color ?  How would you go about changing the color?

Comment: @leora: If you can select the text you can then "fill" it with the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally get around it - using CS6:

1. Duplicate original image into another layer
2. Select & delete the text from the original layer
3. Select & delete everything not text from the duplicated layer.
4. Now you have 2 layers, one without text & one with text
5. Select the text layer and use the colour overlay to change its
   colour
6. Merge layers back together